# Browserify modules cannot be referenced from index.html after including bundle.js script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I'm using Browserify to access a Node module from an index.html file (hosted on Google App Engine)

I import the module in a "main.js" file, as I see is the standard in the Browserify documentation, as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
```

I then bundle this up into a bundle.js file using the following command:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

This successfully produces the required bundle.js file. I then include this at the top of the header in my index.html as follows:

```
<HEAD>
   <script src="/scripts/bundle.js"></script>

   <script src="/scripts/util/loader.js"></script>
   <!-- More scripts below here -->
```

A script within the body of index.html then makes a call to a function within loader.js which uses the line

```
request('api.my-url.com/world').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/resources/myMap.json'));
```

Which I use to attempt to create a file containing the contents of the response. However, when I deploy this on GAE, and access index.html, I am greeted by the error message:

```
loader.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at loadWorld (loader.js:15)
    at Object.create ((index):55)
```

If I try and move the request() call up into the script in index.html I get the same problem, but if I move the line into main.js, I no longer get this issue.

I assume this is down to a personal misunderstanding of Javascript, but I can't seem to figure out why the request object is not available in index.html after bundle.js has been included in index.html via a script tag.

Many thanks to anyone who can shed some light on the situation, thanks.

Comment: Typically, the bundle will include the entire application. Are you bundling `requrest` solely for use in further scripts in the `index.html`? If that's the case, the answer is pretty simple. However, your invalid use of `fs` makes your question difficult to understand - as it will never work. Can you reduce what it is your are trying to do to a simple statement?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a browserify bundle, it is intended to be the application's "entry-point".  But it seems that here you have your entry-point in index.html, so what you want is to bundle a standalone library.

Browserify has an option called `--standalone` to do this, which generates a UMD bundle instead: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#standalone

You invoke it in much the same way, but specify what name (in the global namespace) the UMD bundle should be given. Eg.

`browserify foo.js --standalone mylib > bundle.js`

Now when you include `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` in your html, subsequent scripts will have be able to reference the `mylib` object.

Here's an example of using the `--standalone` option:

- https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor/tree/master/example-umd
- https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor/blob/master/package.json#L9

Also, if you want something like `request` that can be used in the browser, https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr has a very similar API.